# Find another way to solve the problem (group an array of objects)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am solving the problem as follows:

I have an array of objects with input format:

```
let allTasks = [
  {
    time: "07-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p1",
        value: 1111
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    time: "07-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p2",
        value: 2222
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    time: "08-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p1",
        value: 3333
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    time: "08-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p2",
        value: 4444
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    time: "09-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p1",
        value: 5555
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    time: "09-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p2",
        value: 6666
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to convert into a format that is formatted as follows:

```
output = [
  {
    p1: [
      ["07-2020",1111],
      ["08-2020",3333],
      ["09-2020",5555],
    ]
  },
  {
    p2: [
      ["07-2020",2222],
      ["08-2020", 4444],
      ["09-2020", 6666],
    ]
  },
  // ... p3, p4....
]
```

I use `reduce()` method to group the objects in an array.

```
let newArr = [];

allTasks.forEach((x,index)=>{
  newArr.push({
    tasks: x.tasks.map(y=>Object.assign(y,{time: x.time}))
  })
})

console.log('newArr',newArr);
let listTask = newArr.flatMap(x=>x.tasks);
let groupData = listTask.reduce((gr,item)=>{
  gr[item.code] = [...gr[item.code] || [],item];
  return gr;
},[])

let newGroupData = Object.entries(groupData).map(([key,data])=>{
  console.log('-------------------------')
  let result = Object.values(data.reduce((arr,item)=>{
    arr[item.time] = arr[item.time] || [item.time];
    arr[item.time].push(item.value);
    return arr;
  },[]));
  return {
    [key]: result
  }
})
console.log('newGroupData',newGroupData)
```

The results have been expected as above. But my code is long, how do I refactor my code and is there a better way to do it ?

Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this --

`allTasks.reduce((o, d) => (o[d['tasks'][0]['code']] = o[d['tasks'][0]['code']] || [], o[d['tasks'][0]['code']].push([d['time'], d['tasks'][0]['value']]), o) , {})
`

Answer (score 3):

#### A different approach

You could flatten the tasks first, with complemented key-value pair of `time`. To array of this

```
[
  ...
  { code: 'p1', value: 1111, time: '07-2020' }
  ...
]
```

After that, group task by code and do some manipulation with the grouped to achieve your expected result

```js
const groupByCode = {}

allTasks
  .flatMap((parentTask) =>
    parentTask.tasks.map((task) => ({ ...task, time: parentTask.time }))
  )
  .forEach((flattenedTask) => {
    if (groupByCode[flattenedTask.code]) {
      groupByCode[flattenedTask.code].push(flattenedTask)
    } else {
      groupByCode[flattenedTask.code] = [flattenedTask]
    }
  })

const res = Object.entries(groupByCode).map(([code, tasks]) => ({
  [code]: tasks.map((task) => [task.time, task.value]),
}))
```

---

#### Full implementation

```js
let allTasks = [
  {
    time: "07-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p1",
        value: 1111,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    time: "07-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p2",
        value: 2222,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    time: "08-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p1",
        value: 3333,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    time: "08-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p2",
        value: 4444,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    time: "09-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p1",
        value: 5555,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    time: "09-2020",
    tasks: [
      {
        code: "p2",
        value: 6666,
      },
    ],
  },
]

const groupByCode = {}

allTasks
  .flatMap((parentTask) =>
    parentTask.tasks.map((task) => ({ ...task, time: parentTask.time }))
  )
  .forEach((flattenedTask) => {
    if (groupByCode[flattenedTask.code]) {
      groupByCode[flattenedTask.code].push(flattenedTask)
    } else {
      groupByCode[flattenedTask.code] = [flattenedTask]
    }
  })

const res = Object.entries(groupByCode).map(([code, tasks]) => ({
  [code]: tasks.map((task) => [task.time, task.value]),
}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
```

---

#### Reference

[Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)